Searching for proof-readers: "The Aftermath of the Ethereum Merge"
Dear Ethereum enthusiast,
I am currently a Business Engineering student at Ghent University in Belgium. As part of my degree requirements, I am conducting research on the Ethereum Merge for my master’s dissertation. My dissertation, titled “The Aftermath of the Ethereum Merge,” will involve a quantitative analysis of Ethereum’s returns post-merge.
To provide a comprehensive understanding for my readers, I have included an overview that spans from the basic principles of blockchain to the specifics of the Ethereum network. While I have abstracted most of the technical details to maintain reader engagement, I aim to provide a complete overview with the correct nuances. With this in mind, I would greatly appreciate it if you could review my literature study and provide feedback. The study is approximately 25 pages long. I understand if you are unable to accommodate this request, but I thought it was worth asking.
If you are unable to assist, could you possibly connect me with individuals who possess a deep understanding of Ethereum and might be interested in aiding my research?
Thank you in advance for your time and consideration. Keep up the excellent work!
Best regards, Simon
